# CIDetectorError: '(String, CIContext?, [String : Any]?) -> CIDetector' is not convertible to '(String, CIContext?, [String : Any]?) -> CIDetector?'

Tags: swift3, xcode8, cidetector

After converting to `Swift 3.0`, for some reason I get this error

> '(String, CIContext?, [String : Any]?) -> CIDetector' is not convertible to '(String, CIContext?, [String : Any]?) -> CIDetector?'

```
//When initiating 
let detector: CIDetector? = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
```

I only get an error when I try to archive. When I run, everything works fine.

Comment: Way to fix this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/40463013/4045472

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CIDetectorTypeQRCode gives error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40409417/cidetectortypeqrcode-gives-error)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good example for the senselessness of explicit type annotations.

Remove the type annotation and let the compiler infer the type

```
let detector = CIDetector(ofType: CIDetectorTypeFace, context: nil, options: [CIDetectorAccuracy: CIDetectorAccuracyHigh])
```

The error message states that the return type is non-optional.

Comment: Thanks @vadian . Still get this error. It does compile. I only get this error when I `Archive`. The type is a `String`, still not sure why this errors pops up.

Answer (score 0):

Don't have reputation to comment, so want to add that this is still a problem in XCode 8.1 a month later. Only on archive. I am infering the type.